My model is giving inconsistent results
"I ran a Polynomial multiple regression model on a dataset with just 98 points. when I ran the model on different subsets of data (training and testing). It gives me r2 value ranging from negative to positive.I know I have fewer number of data points. I want to ask if I can stick to the run with the highest positive r2 value. Also, how do I save that model if I need to run it later on? Because when I closed the r window and ran the code again, I didn't get the same r2 value and results but a different highest positive r2".
"I am working in r, and I tried other different models as well, like random forest and SVM. But I find PMLR best. But I am getting inconsistent r2 values".

$R^2$ should never be negative. Can you show your code and, ideally, the data as well?  To save R code, use some sort of editor. R Studio is very popular.

You've got just 98 observations. Overlaying these data points with predictions from the model can be very helpful to figure out what's going on. (What's going on in this case is probably the model failing to represent the data well.)

A negative-r-squared is possible, depending on the calculation, so that does not necessarily indicate a bug in your code. However, the statistical interpretation of $R^2<0$ is a poor model fit, as such a value typically comes from comparing the sum of squared residuals of your model to the sum of squared residuals for a naïve benchmark model that always predicts the same value.
By testing multiple holdout sets, you get a sense of how your model would perform on new data. If the result is that the model often fits quite poorly, worse than even a naïve benchmark model, that is a strong signal that the model needs to be improved, even though the model sometimes fits quite well.

To split the data the same way every time, I would recommend the set.seed function, though the coding details are outside the scope of Cross Validated.
